# VQMOD replace not working with multi line search

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

There is a function in opencart which I need to replace as following:

```
protected function validateDelete() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'catalog/download')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
```

Should be:

```
protected function validateDelete() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('delete', 'catalog/download')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission_delete');
```

I have tried:

```
<search position="replace"><![CDATA[
            protected function validateDelete() {
                if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify',]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            protected function validateDelete() {
                if (!$this->user->hasPermission('delete',
            ]]></add>
```

but its not working. The third line appears in multiple locations, so cant just replace in single line.

Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiple line search cannot be done in vqmod. So you need to use the vqmod `index` attribute.  If the “Search” string is 'hello' and there are 5 'hello's in the file, but you only want to replace the 1st and 3rd, use Index: 1,3.

So change your vqmod code as below:

```
<operation>
    <search position="replace" index="3"><![CDATA[if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'catalog/download')) {]]></search>
    <add><![CDATA[
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('delete', 'catalog/download')) {
    ]]></add>
</operation>
<operation>
    <search position="replace" index="3"><![CDATA[$this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');]]></search>
    <add><![CDATA[
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission_delete');
    ]]></add>
</operation>
```

Don't forget to update the `index` value.

Reference links: https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/opencart-vqmod-tutorial/ , http://code.google.com/p/vqmod/wiki/Scripting

Have a nice day !!

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I need to verify occurrence on desired number.